# Why "Duplicate local variable messages" here?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

After consulting 33-35 lines of code from: https://github.com/springinpractice/sip04/blob/04/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/users/registrationForm.jsp.

```
<form:errors path="username">
     <div class="errorMessage"><form:errors path="username" htmlEscape="false" /></div>
</form:errors>
```

As soon as I save that file, I get an error on the second line under `"username"` in MyEclipse:

```
Duplicate local variable messages.
```

Why this error happens and how to solve it.

But that jsp page can be rendered without any error.

**EDIT**

I am trying to do form validation, this is my code:

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%
String path = request.getContextPath();
String basePath = request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+path+"/";
%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1><spring:message code="user.registration.heading"/></h1>  

    <form:form action="" modelAttribute="user" method="POST">

        <form:errors path="*">
            <div><spring:message code="error.global"/></div>
        </form:errors>

        <!-- for username -->
        <div>
            <div style="display: inline-block; width: 100px;">
                <spring:message code="user.registration.label.username" />              
            </div>
            <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <form:input path="username" />
                <form:errors path="username">
                    <div class="errorMessage"><form:errors path="username" htmlEscape="false" /></div>
                </form:errors>
            </div>
        </div>


        password: <form:input path="password" />   <form:errors path="password"/><br/>
        confirm password: <form:input path="confirmPassword" />  <form:errors path="confirmPassword"/> <br/>
        name: <form:input path="name" />   <form:errors path="name"/><br/>
        email: <form:input path="email" />   <form:errors path="email"/><br/>
        department: <form:input path="department" />  <form:errors path="department"/>. <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    </form:form>

  </body>
</html>
```

This is the screenshot of that error:

[image]

Comment: Where/when do you get that exception?

Comment: On a first glance the error message you quote seems completely unrelated to the code you listed. You will need to provide more information: What do you do with the code, when does the error appear, what makes you think that the affected line of code is really the one you mention, etc.?

Comment: It may be just warning in eclipse.. if so just ignore it

Answer (score 3):

This is probably related to the implementation of `form:errors`. A glance into the tag library `spring-form.tld` reveals that the tag defines a variable called `messages`:

```
<!-- <form:errors/> -->
<tag>
   <name>errors</name>
   <tag-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.ErrorsTag</tag-class>
   <body-content>JSP</body-content>
   <description>Renders field errors in an HTML 'span' tag.</description>
   <variable>
      <name-given>messages</name-given>
      <variable-class>java.util.List</variable-class>
   </variable>
```

I did not manage to find the original source of the tag library but you can inspect it here: http://www.docjar.com/docs2web/inside/spring-webmvc-2.5.6.jar/detail/META-INF/spring-form.tld

The fact that you nest a form:errors into another form:errors might be the source of this message.

Answer (score 1):

MyEclipse compiles JSP files as soon as you save them. The resulting Java code is a bit different for each app server, so it's quite possible that you get an error on one of them but not the other.

To find out what is going on, you need to look at the source code that MyEclipse generates. I'm not sure where the file is created, though. Search for "*registrationForm*.java" in the workspace (probably outside of Eclipse) and if you don't find anything there, search your whole harddisk.

Then open this file and look inside. You may want to put a pattern close to the error like `<% /*XXX*/ %>`. This will show up in the generated Java code so you can search for it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug in Eclipse. Nested form:errors tags are valid. Apparently Eclipse gets confused over it and shows the above message.

To be clear: the nested tags work fine, it is not an error of any kind.